# Issue with tcl (tkinter) after building python app with snapcraft

Tags: python, ubuntu-22.04, snapcraft

Issue with tkinter + snapcraft

After using snapcraft to build an app of a python script with tkinter, I get the following error when running my app:

> _tkinter.TclError: Can't find a usable init.tcl in the following directories:
> /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 /snap/shortcut1/x1/usr/lib/tcl8.6 /snap/shortcut1/x1/lib/tcl8.6 /snap/shortcut1/x1/usr/library /snap/shortcut1/x1/library /snap/shortcut1/x1/tcl8.6.8/library /snap/shortcut1/tcl8.6.8/library
>
> This probably means that Tcl wasn't installed properly.

However, init.tcl does exist in /usr/share/tcltk/tcl8.6 and doesn't appear to have any glaring issues. The app will not run and I can't get past this error.

I've attempted to reinstall tcl with sudo apt install tcl but behavior doesn't change.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.